# How to list auto-loaded packages?

Tags: autoload, introspection

Some packages are auto-loaded, others need be be explicitly loaded with `require`.

How can I programmatically generate a list of packages that emacs auto-loads?

(I'd assume this list would include `subr` & `simple` but not `calculator` for e.g.).

---

*For some context I'm developing a tool that needs a list of symbols which are available without them being explicitly required, so I need to be able to have a "default" list of symbols which we can assume will be defined.*

Comment: `(let (l) (mapatoms (lambda (sym) (when (autoloadp (symbol-function sym)) (push sym l)))) l)` gives the symbols with function definition that are not yet auto-loaded.